# Wordpress images not displaying in pages

Tags: wordpress, image, http-status-code-404

Today my website (www.bocconicsa.com) suddenly started not showing any images neither the logo. I didn't do any changes or installed new plugins these days. Google console says error 404 file not found. But from the admin panel in "media library" I can see all the images.
The installed plugins are:
- Akismet Anti-Spam
- All In One SEO Pack
- Better Search Replace
- Elementor
- Orbit Fox Companion
- Really SImple SSL
- yoast seo
- remove footer credit
- team members

This is the .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

No idea on how to fix this.
Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your images are being served by an Image Optimization Service - I think this is included in the Orbit Fox Companion plugin you mentioned. Look for an Orbit Fox setting to either flush the image cache or not use their CDN function at all.

Answer (score 0):

First, you check your image folder path. and upload this code in a config.php file

```
define('UPLOADS' , 'wp-content/myimages');
```

Comment: Did it, but still don't show images. From google console the error is "GET https://www.bocconicsa.com/8cc2e96585fbd4a48989f20776c37d25/1745/871/55/https/www.bocconicsa.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Bocconicsa-logo-slogan.png 404 (not found)". The link to the image is very weird...

Comment: Update your permalinks once set it form default